# It is possible to define a large amount of specific open graph actions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, open-graph-beta

it is possible and/or useful du define a big amount of specific Actions in a Facebook Application?

e.g.

#### First way, **generic** action: do

- User A *does* "cooking italien spaghetti" on my App
- User A *does* "baking a cookie" on my App

So I define the specific part over my object-title.

#### Second way, **specific** actions:

- User A *is cooking* "italien spaghetti" on my App
- User A *is baking* "cookies" on my App

All Actions has to be approved by Facebook.
The user could have a more interesting interaction with the graph.
The maintenance-level would be higher.

Any opinion or experience?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Always do option 2. We will never approve actions that have objects embedded in them.

Comment: But the action in first example is **do**.
"baking a cookie" would be the object-title.

Would Facebook accecpt n(maybe 40-100) specific actions for my app?

Comment: Try and see. Probably not. Also, "do" is a pretty crappy verb. We are trying to add more semantic meaning to the graph, not just generic edge connections.